# Mongoose finds match, but doesn't modify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm new to Mongoose and haven't been able to figure out how to use the updateOne() function.

```
    const statusChannelIDSchema = require('../models/statusChannelIDs.js');


    var filter = {guildId: guildId};
    var update = {$set: {statusChannelID: statusChannelID}};
    statusChannelIDSchema.updateOne(filter, update, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

console.log(result) will output:

```
null
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

So it matches, but doesn't modify. Not sure what the "null" is doing there.

This is my /models/statusChannelIDs.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const statusChannelIDSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    statusChannelID: Number,
    guildId: {
       type: Number,
       required: true,
       unique: true
    },
    userId: Number,
    channelId: Number,
    msgId: Number,
    userName: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("statusChannelIDs", statusChannelIDSchema);
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I debug mongoose better?

Comment: Your guildId and statusChannelID are Number types according with your schema, try in the updateOne provide the same type as well and not String.

Comment: @FernandoZamperin you mean like this?
  var filter = {guildId: guildId};
  var update = {$set: {statusChannelID: statusChannelID}}
Above code returns the exact same result
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes but are both variables type Number?

Comment: @FernandoZamperin I checked with typof and made sure by using parseInt(), still same result.

Comment: Try this instead to see if it works -> statusChannelIDSchema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err)); PS: Without the $set

Comment: @FernandoZamperin 
It returns an object with inside something odd: guildId: 748620006807437300,
This number isn't known to me, not even sure where it gets it from. No guildId in the DB has that number, also when logging the guildId before the update runs, it's a different number (the right one). Why does that happen? Where does it get it from?

Comment: @KenjiBailly try using  function with await this will return updated document,it may help you in achieving what you want.
 static async  updateOne(query, updateData) {
        return userModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, updateData, { new: true }).lean().exec();
    };

Comment: I tried that just now, it says that .lean and .exec are not a function.
Is my model wrong?
const statusChannelIDSchema = require('../models/statusChannelIDs.js');

See above code

Answer (score 0):

After long debugging I managed to find the problems:

1. I'm using it for discord.js and their ID's are pretty long (longer than a standard int), so you have to store them as strings or they get parsed pretty weird.
2. The collections in the database can't have capital letters